# mysql: fast group by with join

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have this query with many left joins and a inner join with dates.
I need to group by id_art (from articles_art) and date_dat (dates_dat). The problem is that is really slow. it takes 3second for 1000records.
dates_dat is indexed in dates_dat table and id_art is a primary key of articles_art.
What can I do to optimize this query?

```
SELECT
    id_art, image2_art, video_art, website,
    text.title_int, text.intro_int, text.text_int, text.extra_int,
    dat.date_dat, dat.date2_dat,
    group_concat(tim.time_tim),
    prd.name_prd,
    group_concat(cat.name_cat),
    trg.name_trg,
    spa.name_spa,
    spa2.name_spa 
FROM
    articles_art AS art
    LEFT JOIN internText_int AS text ON text.idart_int = art.id_art
    INNER JOIN dates_dat AS dat ON art.id_art = dat.idart_dat
    LEFT JOIN spaces_spa As spa ON spa.id_spa = dat.idspa_dat
    LEFT JOIN spaces_spa As spa2 ON spa.id_spa = dat.idspa2_dat
    LEFT JOIN times_tim AS tim ON tim.iddat_tim = dat.id_dat
    LEFT JOIN articles_products_artprd AS artprd ON artprd.idart_artprd = art.id_art
    LEFT JOIN products_prd AS prd ON prd.id_prd = artprd.idprd_artprd
    LEFT JOIN cater_cev AS cev ON cev.idart_cev = dat.idart_dat
    LEFT JOIN categories_cat AS cat ON cat.id_cat = cev.idcat_cev
    LEFT JOIN targets_trg AS trg ON trg.id_trg = art.idtrg_art   
WHERE
    prd.id_prd in (1,2)
    AND validated_art = 1
    AND text.idlin_int in (1,4)
GROUP BY
    id_art, date_dat
```

Comment: Can you post the explain plan?

Comment: indexes are the key to performance in a select query - adding an explain from your query will help identify where you are lacking indexes.

Comment: How the explain of the query should help? I see the possible_keys, key, ref, rows and extra but I don't know how this can help me. Can you explain me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look like you can put an index on these columns

```
prd.id_prd
validated_art 
text.idlin_int
```

Test this first then if this does not work put indexes on column conditions on the ON clause

Answer (score 0):

If data latency isn't an issue, can you hive the data off (perhaps overnight?) into a single normalised table?  That way you query a single table without all those JOINS.  You could even apply indexes to help speed things up further.

Comment: the join is not the problem, because with only joins it takes 7-10ms. The problem is group by.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Assuming latency is not an issue, could you normalise the GROUP BY data overnight?